# ngfor display not according to array received

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6

Below is the object i receive from the backend

```
{
"30-04-2022": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 3,
        "amount": 178000,
        "created_at": "2022-04-30T17:12:12.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-30T08:39:45.000000Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 4,
        "amount": 101500,
        "created_at": "2022-04-30T20:13:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-30T08:39:33.000000Z",
    
    }
],
"24-04-2022": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 3,
        "amount": 178000,
        "created_at": "2022-04-30T17:12:12.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-30T08:39:45.000000Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 4,
        "amount": 101500,
        "created_at": "2022-04-30T20:13:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-30T08:39:33.000000Z",
    }
]}
```

But the display in ngfor is reversed. Cant understand why this is happening. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

is there a way to display items as it is show in the object without reversing its order

Comment: Do you have the data stored in a variable after the rest call, if so you could try the reverse() method on it before sending it to the template

Comment: @NobleEugene yes i do store it in a variable, this.allTypeOrders. I have tried reverse() method but it didn't seem to work. This is my ngfor: *ngFor="let item of allTypeOrders | keyvalue". I have tried this.allTypeOrders.reverse()

Comment: Then try the reverse method and see if it works consistently

Comment: @NobleEugene   this.allTypeOrders.reverse() isnt working

Comment: can you post the html code and can you console log the object?